# What questions led Cayley to the definition of matrix multiplication?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, linear-algebra

quote:
every book I've seen on matrix algebra or linear algebra seem[s] to just define the matrix operations without providing any historical background

Talk:Matrix multiplication - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AMatrix_multiplication

relevant material:
When was Matrix Multiplication invented?
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/history/matrix/

Matrices and determinants
http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/HistTopics/Matrices_and_determinants.html

EDIT:
I have now found many links discussing the rationale for matrix multiplication,
but in particular I am looking for primary sources for Cayley other than:
A Memoir on the Theory of Matrices on JSTOR
http://www.jstor.org/stable/108649?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271927/why-historically-do-we-multiply-matrices-as-we-do

Comment: thank you @KCd, from that I have found the following links:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271927/why-historically-do-we-multiply-matrices-as-we-do  
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192835/fastest-and-intuitive-ways-to-look-at-matrix-multiplication  
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131889/how-many-geometrical-interpretations-does-matrix-multiplication-have

A Brief History of Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory  
http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120910034016/http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~vitulli/441.sp04/LinAlgHistory.html